# why the catkin_init_workspace command is not included as a step in the InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment tutorial?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More than a question is just a suggestion to update this tutorial.  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262990/why-the-catkin_init_workspace-command-is-not-included-as-a-step-in-the-installingandconfiguringrosenvironment-tutorial?/) by [lenguini](https://answers.ros.org/users/30593/lenguini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that the wiki is community maintained, if you think that things should be updated feel free to contribute.

Also note that for quite some time, `catkin_make` automatically initializes the workspace if it hasn't been initialized. So there is no need to explicitly call `catkin_init_workspace` anymore (not exactly sure when this change happened). I still find myself calling `catkin_init_workspace` manually mostly out of habit, and it certainly doesn't cause any problems. I think you are referring to [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment), which works perfectly on my machine.

See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/187084/what-does-the-command-catkin_init_workspace-do/) for more, or check the [catkin_make source code](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/d0c4ecb3bac9b38a0883253e1e350d3fb72c4a6f/bin/catkin_make#L130-L136) that actually initializes the workspace if required.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lenguini](https://answers.ros.org/users/30593/lenguini/) on 2017-06-02**:
Thanks for your reply jarvisschultz.  For some reason I had to type catkin_init_workspace, otherwise catkin_make thrown out an error, and no CMakelist.txt file was created in the src folder.  I've installed ros indigo, so maybe this could be the reason?  Also I'm using a python virtual environment..

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-06-02**:
ROS Indigo likely isn't the issue, but perhaps your virtual environment is. Without knowing what error was thrown by `catkin_make`, it's tough to say.